# I am trying to index a Dictionary but I don't know how. I am trying to access the data in "rates" but can't seem to get in there

Tags: c#, json, api

Down below is what I am working with.
I am making a app that calculate the wholesale and retail prices from the first price in a different currency.

I am trying to get the exchange rates using a API.
The api returns clean data that I have supplied below.
But I still can't seem to get access to the "rates" part of it.
My goal is to grab the CAD, USD, GBP, EUR. But I don't know how.
It would mean a lot if you can help me. And yes I am quite new to C#

```
namespace Formulation
{
    public class Currencies
    {
        public static double EUR { get; set; }
        public static double CAD { get; set;  }
        public static double GBP { get; set; }
        public static double USD { get; set;}
        public static HttpClient apiClient;
        public async Task<object> CallExchangeRateAPI()
        {
            apiClient = new HttpClient();
            apiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            apiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            Uri url = new Uri("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=AUD");
            using (var response = await apiClient.GetAsync(url))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                IDictionary data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary>(responseBody);
                return data;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The data that I am trying to access

```
{
  "rates": {
    "CAD": 0.9741461251,
    "HKD": 5.902667765,
    "ISK": 98.9164184779,
    "PHP": 36.5762625943,
    "DKK": 4.7129459477,
    "HUF": 225.2772321146,
    "CZK": 16.4279830176,
    "GBP": 0.5585514226,
    "RON": 3.0881439706,
    "SEK": 6.4193016919,
    "IDR": 10679.221849059,
    "INR": 55.5215132121,
    "BRL": 4.0717318294,
    "RUB": 57.804765224,
    "HRK": 4.7964641024,
    "JPY": 80.0012673468,
    "THB": 22.8825803181,
    "CHF": 0.6846207465,
    "EUR": 0.6336734047,
    "MYR": 3.0847855016,
    "BGN": 1.239338445,
    "TRY": 5.458209239,
    "CNY": 4.9187630695,
    "NOK": 6.5610544325,
    "NZD": 1.0579177492,
    "ZAR": 11.3688612889,
    "USD": 0.7614853305,
    "MXN": 15.3469361891,
    "SGD": 1.0152081617,
    "AUD": 1,
    "ILS": 2.5153665801,
    "KRW": 849.7750459413,
    "PLN": 2.846270832
  },
  "base": "AUD",
  "date": "2021-02-03"
}
```

I can't seem to get the information in "rates"
I am tried for looping thru but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: You are not far off, but the JSON object doesn't deserialize to an IDictionary

Comment: Your Json is not Dictionary.  it has three properties rates,base,Date. create to convert json to that class.

Comment: this is Dictionary json sample . string json = @"{""key1"":""value1"",""key2"":""value2""}";

var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io?share=bMM28oZJo2WqhoE2Qjhc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Globalization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

public partial class RatesModel
{
    [JsonProperty("rates")]
    public Dictionary<string, double> Rates { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("base")]
    public string Base { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("date")]
    public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }
}
```

Use the above DTO for your response, you should be able to deserialize to a RatesModel object:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RatesModel>(responseBody);
```

Thereafter you can index a specific rate as follows

```
double rate = data.Rates["BGN"];
```

For your reference, there is a useful tool for mapping JSON to a C# model: https://app.quicktype.io/

For a full working implementation see this fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/JekzHG courtesy of [Jamiec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/219661/jamiec)

Comment: Why is `as double` needed?

Comment: I think it would be worthwhile mentioning the tool which you used to generate the code as well, although that is up to you.

Comment: Seeing as I was very close to writing much the same answer, feel free to include this live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JekzHG

Answer (score 2):

You can parse like that:

```
public class Currencies
{
    public static double EUR { get; set; }
    public static double CAD { get; set; }
    public static double GBP { get; set; }
    public static double USD { get; set; }
    public static HttpClient apiClient;
    public async Task<object> CallExchangeRateAPI()
    {
        apiClient = new HttpClient();
        apiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        apiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        Uri url = new Uri("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=AUD");
        using (var response = await apiClient.GetAsync(url))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(responseBody);
            var rates = data.Rates;
            CAD = rates["CAD"];
            USD = rates["USD"];
            GBP = rates["GBP"];
            EUR = rates["EUR"];
            return data;
        }
    }

    class Data
    {
        public Dictionary<string, double> Rates { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And of course you should add using to use generic (statically-typed) Dictionary on top of the file:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Comment: @mjwills This should work. I checked it before post.